# 0 Image uploading using CKEditor in asp.net website

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have downloaded the Ck editor 3.6.4.As per the installation steps given in the documentation. I also integrated in my asp.net page.

ckEditor is displaying. But While inserting a image,a dialog box appears.
I selected the upload tab, After I browse a particular image.
I clicked "Send It server" button. I got a message of image url is missing.

The following is the code in my asp.net page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server" FilebrowserImageBrowseUrl='ckeditor/images/'  FilebrowserImageUploadUrl='ckeditor/images/'></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only configuration settings in CKEditor are the paths to the upload tool.

The upload tool is responsible for uploading the file to the correct directory and returning that directory path to CKEditor when you click "OK".

The "Image Source URL Is Missing" error message seems to indicate that the uploader isn't passing the URL to CKEditor in a way that CKEditor can understand it.

This page in the Developers Guide explains how to pass the the URL to CKEditor:
[Integrating CKEditor with a Custom File Browser](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29/Custom_File_Browser)

About halfway down the page is this section:
Passing the URL of the Selected File

Thanks,

Curtsy : http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Image-Source-URL-Missing-1

Comment: Thanks for your answer I referred that link....Can you tell me, how to call that javascript fuction in my ckeditor,I tried as follows,             FilebrowserImageUploadUrl="getUrlParam()"  But still I got the same message as Image source Url missing..

Comment: I haven't used it. I just found the link to answer and think that this is the same question from what are you suffering, so I have pasted it along with link. You may find answer from that forums.